# can I attach IAM role to instance after launching it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, s3cmd

Getting error :

```
root@omp_affiliate_backend ~]# s3cmd get s3://admarvel-noc/all-users/nrpe-plugins.tar.gz .
s3://admarvel-noc/all-users/nrpe-plugins.tar.gz -> ./nrpe-plugins.tar.gz  [1 of 1]
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (Forbidden):
```

Is it due to iam role ? As no iam role is assigned to omp_affiliate_backend server where as another server has iam role(AmazonS3FullAccess) could easily download that tar.

If yes can I attach Iam role to instance after launching it ie now ? If not how do I download from that bucket ?

Comment: No, you can't. You should launch a new instance with a role. Barring that, you'll have to make your own AWS IAM user, provision API keys, and provide them to `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You should launch a new instance with a role. Barring that, you'll have to make your own AWS IAM user, provision API keys, and provide them to s3cmd